# django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:

Tags: python, django

In case related_name is specify in the fields and the  realted model does not have the record, django raise the following error while accessing the related_name

```
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
```

Here is the example code:

```
from django.conf import settings

User  = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
class Partner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 'partner_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in shell

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import *
 user1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
 user1.partner_user

  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 389, in __get__
  self.related.get_accessor_name()
 django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no partner_user
```

**At present I am using this solution**

```
hasattr(user1, 'partner_user') and user1.partner_user or []
```

Any better solution  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `hasattr` looks OK. I would recommend using a conditional expression instead of the `and or` trick:

```
user1.partner_user if hasattr(user1, 'partner_user') else []
```

You can simplify it by using `getattr` with a default

```
getattr(user1, 'partner_user', [])
```

Finally, I'm surprised that you are using an empty list when the related object does not exist. I would expect to see `None` instead.

```
getattr(user1, 'partner_user', None)
```

Comment: But passing default to `getattr` will simplify it `getattr(user1, 'partner_user', None)`

Comment: @AamirAdnan yes, good point, I've updated the answer to use `getattr(user1, 'partner_user', None)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just messed up.